# Filter table on specific column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working example over here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/g6geH12xCI8EirNvghsW?p=preview

you can see that if you select "Mark" in the select box it will filter my table and show both:

John Mark

and

Mark Poet

and I only want it to filter on the 2nd column... so show Mark Poet ONLY.

I appreciate any helpful tips.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {


    $('#mySelector').change(function () {
        var selection = $(this).val();
        $('table')[selection ? 'show' : 'hide']();

        if (selection) {
            $.each($('#myTable tbody tr'), function (index, item) {
                $(item)[$(item).is(':contains(' + selection + ')') ? 'show' : 'hide']();
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reduce your selection to the desired td, for example like that

`$(item)[$(item).find('td:nth-child(2)').is(':contains('+ selection  +')')? 'show' : 'hide']();`

NOTE: reducing the selection at the `each` level won't work, because you wouldn't hide the wole row but each `td` individually

working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/yabW9OgQEE5Fb3efF8Q0?p=preview

Comment: or `td:eq(1)` instead of `td:nth-child(2)`

Answer (score 1):

Consider selecting the `td` elements using the `nth-child(n)` css selctor.

e.g.

```
td:nth-child(2)
```

or

```
$("#myTable tbody tr td:nth-child(2)")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try $("#myTable tbody tr td:nth-child(2)"). this should work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you always want to filter on the 2nd column, this would work:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#mySelector').change(function() {
    var selection = $(this).val();
    $('table')[selection ? 'show' : 'hide']();

    if (selection) {
      $('#myTable tbody tr').each(function() {
        var $name = $(this).find("td").first().next();
        var $row = $name.parent();
        if ($name.text() != selection) {
          $row.hide();
        } else {
          $row.show();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to target second `td` with `td:eq(1)`... index starts from `0`.

Also, the `.` notation is more readable, so I'd use `.show()` and `.hide()`.

Further, I didn't get why you would show or hide the table itself, but if that's unintentional, just show all the rows before filtering instead. That will display all rows when "Please Select" is selected. At present after making a selection and then selecting "please select" will hide the table completely. So you can use code like:

https://plnkr.co/edit/M5dyYwiL4ZO9qwnZMMKc?p=preview

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#mySelector').change(function() {
    var selection = $(this).val(),
      row = $('#myTable tbody tr');
    row.show(); // show all rows to ensure no row remains hidden

    if (selection) {
      // hide the row that doesn't contain selected val td:eq(1)
      row.filter(function(index, item) {
        return $(item).find('td:eq(1)').text().indexOf(selection) === -1;
      }).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <select id='mySelector' class="styled-select slate">
       <option value="">Please Select</option>
       <option value='John'>John</option>
       <option value='Mark'>Mark</option>
       <option value='Ace'>Ace</option>
    </select>
  <br><br><br>
  <table id='myTable'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ids</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1,2</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Poet</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2,3</td>
        <td>Ace</td>
        <td>Ventura</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```